# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el resultado de los datos en mysql con js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

trato de obtener los clientes guardando en una variable para retornarlos y no puedo, si me puede ayudar se lo agradezco de ante mano.

```
function listarClientes() {
    let clientes

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients';
    conex.conexionMysql.query(sql, (error, resul) => {
        clientes = resul;
    });

    return clientes;
}

let clientes = listarClientes();
```

Comment: Esa consulta no es optima, procura siempre utilizar una condicion para traer ciertos registros, se que es un ejemplo, pero por si depronto lo estas haciendo tal cual nunca lo hagas en un ambiente de produccion.

Comment: Hola! @Jose deberías aclarar porque no puedes, si obtienes algún error, etc, edita tu pregunta y agrega todos los detalles que puedas para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte! saludos!!